# How to copy symlinks to a device that does not support symlinks?

Tags: linux, backup, samba, symbolic-link, cp

I am trying to backup a directory to a Samba share, which apparently does not support symlinks.

Are there any good solutions of how to proceed?

I would suggest a sensible behaviour might be to

- Dereference and copy symlinks (copy the file) if the symlink is valid
- Ignore the symlink (do not copy anything) if the symlink is invalid

Reason for this is I have some analysis project where there were some symlinks which used to point to some large input data. These are no longer valid because the data was on a seperate location. Loosing this information (not copying the symlinks) is unimportant.

There may be other symlinks which link to real files which still exist, however, and I would like to preserve these.

I'm aware I could tarball the directory, which I will do, for a second copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cp` with the parameter `-L` (also available as `--dereference`) so that it copies the original file rather than a symlink.